# neovimへのlazy.nvimの導入に際してエラーが出る

Tags: neovim

[Neovimのプラグインってどうやっていれるの？](https://zenn.dev/vim_jp/articles/20231113vim_ekiden#%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B0%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%8D%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A3%E3%83%BC(lazy.nvim))を参考にして`lazy.nvim`をwsl上の仮想ubuntuに導入しています。

次節の「設定を変更してみる」の直前のNeovimを再起動して云々の下りまではよかったんですが、指示通りにneovimを再起動するとエラーが出ます。

一応、nvimの起動自体はできますが、それ以上のことはよくわかりません…

[image: エラー内容]

## 環境

### ディレクトリ

```
~/.config/nvim/
├── init.lua
└── plugins
    └── lazy.lua

1 directory, 2 files
```

- Ubuntu: 22.04 LTS
- wsl: 2.0.9.0
- neovim: 0.9
- lazy.nvim: 10.15

Comment: 「エラーが出た」で終わらずに、まずはそのエラーメッセージで検索してみることをお勧めします (調べた結果、分からなかったらの質問は大いに構いません)。また、画面キャプチャではなくメッセージを文字のまま質問に貼り付けてください。 /  `init.lua` の内容も合わせて質問に追記してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

フォルダ構成が間違ってました。正しくは

```
.config/nvim/
├── init.lua
└── lua
    └── plugins
        └── lazy.lua
```

でした。